# Pygame Obstacles

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am working on a Pygame game. The premise of the game is you must dodge obstacles that start at the bottom of the screen and move upward to create the illusion the player is falling. I already have a player sprite and need help with the obstacle class. When I try to initialize my Obstacle class, I get an error.

```
class Obstable(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width):
            pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.image = pygame.surface([width, 50])
            self.image.fill(black)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
BLACK = (0,0,0)
obst1 = Obstacle(BLACK, 100)
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: My problem right now is that I get an error when I try to make an instance of my Obstacle object. I will edit in the code I have so far.

Answer (score 2):

The class is named Obstable, you instantiate it as Obstacle. Simple Typo.
Would be even easier if you included the NameError Exception. Saying "I get an Error" is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your class is named `Obstable`. See the problem? You will need to change it to `Obstacle`. This should fix problem number one. Once you fix this, and run your code, you should run into another mistake.

Your second problem appears to be that you are referencing an undefined variable in the Obstacle class.

```
class Obstable(pg.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, color, width):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.surface([width, 50])
        self.image.fill(black)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

The error is here:

```
self.image.fill(black)
```

The variable `black` is undefined. Instead, you need to change `black` to `self.color`, but before you can do that, you must initialize `self.color`. I fixed your code for you:

```
class Obstacle(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width):
            self.color = color
            pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.image = pygame.surface([width, 50])
            self.image.fill(self.color)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
BLACK = (0,0,0)
obst1 = Obstacle(BLACK, 100)
```

Hopefully my answer was of assistance to you!